# HttpContext.Current.Request.Form checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am posting my form to an MVC Controller, where I want to process some changes the user has made on a grid like html structure.

I have checkboxes rendered as simple HTML in my View for each row :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxR1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxR2" checked="checked" />
```

I would like to know how I would retrieve a checkbox value after an AJAX post.

I am trying to use the following to retrieve the

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["cbxR1"]
```

and am always getting a null, regardless of whether the checkbox was checked or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cbxR1`, `cbxR2` should be the name of an input element, not the id.

```
<form ...>

<input type="checkbox" name="cbxR1" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxR2" checked="checked" />

</form>
```

Comment: ok, that gets me the value, but how do I get a checked status server side?

Comment: @TK1 Just return the JsonResult by an action method and then retrieve it on the `success` method of the AJAX request.

Comment: I got it ... the value that I get server side is "on" if a checkbox is checked.

Comment: @TK1 you also could add the `value='false'` attribute to a checkbox to change the value you get on the serverside from `on/off` to `true/false` and therefore be able to declare a `bool` variable to retrieve that checkbox value.